# Configure Apache Client Certificate Authentication for proxy

Tags: apache, ssl

I have 3 Backend API servers(HTTPS), API servers have different authorization permissions for different users based on user certificate, I am configuring apache to load balance the 3 backend servers, like below

```
<VirtualHost *:zzzz>
       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile /path/to/server.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/server.key
       SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/ca.crt
       SSLProxyEngine on
       SSLProxyVerify none
       SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
       SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
       SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
       <Proxy balancer://api_server>
           BalancerMember https://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy
           BalancerMember https://xx.xx.xx.xx:yyyy
       </Proxy>
       ProxyPass / balancer://api_server/
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that when a client request `apache`, with certificates, only the request goes to the API server, not the certificates, and API server responses unauthorized user, I tried using `SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile`, but it only accepts one set of certificate, and every time passes the same certificate, but in this case, the authorization happens only based on certificates.

Is there a way to blindly forward HTTPS request to API? or any other suggestions is warmly welcomed.

Comment: Instead of load balancer your can try proxyPass.

Comment: @NitinDhomse  The ultimate goal is not to overload a single server, I tried proxyPass though, but not helping

Comment: The user talks to Apache, then Apache talks to the balanced machines.  That's the point of a proxy, it ensures clients do not talk to servers directly.  So from the balanced server perspective, Apache is the client.  Only way I can see doing that is to use a layer 4 network load balancer which does not do SSL offloading.  i.e. not Apache.

Comment: @Nic3500 Thanks I configured Nginx Layer 4 load balancer and now its working fine :) happy holiday..

Comment: np, I converted my comment into an answer, when you have 2 sec, please accept.  Happy holidays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming the comment into an answer since it solved the OP's question.

The user talks to Apache, then Apache talks to the balanced machines. That's the point of a proxy, it ensures clients do not talk to servers directly. So from the balanced server perspective, Apache is the client.

Only way I can see doing that is to use a layer 4 network load balancer which does not do SSL offloading. i.e. not Apache

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to AJP instead of HTTP proxy, as explained in the Apache doc : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html

If I understand well what you're saying, you need the client certificate to be forwarded, which is a feature of AJP :

> Request Packet Structure
>
> ?ssl_cert 0x07    String

Comment: my back end servers only accepts HTTPS requests, I configured nginx layer 4 load balancer and now its working fine..